# In $\mathbb C^2$, Show that $\langle x,y\rangle=xAy*$ is an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

$A= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&i\\
      -i&2
    \end{array}
\right] $

I've shown that

(a) $\langle x,y+z\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z\rangle$.

(b) $\langle cx,y\rangle=c\langle x,y\rangle$.

(c) $\overline{\langle x,y\rangle} = \ \langle y,x\rangle$.

but, i'm not getting how to show $\langle x,x\rangle>0 $, if $x$ is not zero.

Please help!!

Comment: @Michael Hardy:Thanks for editing

Comment: Hint: Consider the cholesky decomposition $A=\bar L L^t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \\ -i & 2 \end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ -i & 1 \end{array}\right]\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

Let $A=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \\ -i & 2 \end{array}\right]$ and let $B=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ -i & 1 \end{array}\right]$.

$$\langle x,x \rangle=xAx^*=xBB^*x^*=(xB)(xB)^*\geq 0$$

Comment: :I liked your method of how you write A=BB*.Is there any general method for doing this?

Comment: In general, this is called cholesky decomposition.

Comment: For 2 by 2 hermitian positive definite matrices if $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & \bar{b} \\  b & c\end{array}\right]$$, then $$B=\left[\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{a} & 0 \\  \frac{b}{\sqrt{a}} & \sqrt{c-\frac{|b|^2}{a}}\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: :EXCELLENT!! Can you give me the proof of this.

Comment: We just have to verify that $BB^*=A$. Also, note that from positive definite, we havae $a>0$ and $ac-|b|^2>0$.

Answer (score 2):

We can see that matrix $A$ is a [hermitian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) with positive eigenvalues, namely $\lambda_1 = 0.382$ and $\lambda_2 = 2.618$. This means that $A$ is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). By definition for every vector $x\neq 0 $ we have that 
$$x^*A x>0$$